# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.recurrent'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to import LSTM in python

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

However, I get below error message on compilation:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.recurrent'

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Comment: These are very old imports, just do from keras.layers import LSTM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you're using the tensorflow version 2.10.0, try this

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
```

you can check it at the link bellow
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM

Answer (score 2):

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

error
Simple just remove the name recurrent
Run

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
```

Error removed by this statement

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
```